# Placing multiple divs in an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a lot of `divs` in my markup look similar to:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

The markup is look **very** messy and i'm fairly new to JS but wondering, if I could place all these divs into an array, then a for loop to iterate over them, then print them. But still have enough control over each div that I can change the background colour on them?

My JS so far:

```
  var div = {
    divInfo: [
      {
        title: "title",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
      }
    ]
  };
```

I've only shown one div at moment, as i'm still struggling with the for loop.

Any help/suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Just use this `document.getElementsByTagName('div')`, then you can use `for` on it.

Comment: @MehdiDehghani That would require that the divs already exist (when the OP wants to create them from script), and that these were the *only* divs on the page. Also, working with the nested container/wrapper divs that way would be tough.

Comment: Use templates like [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

Comment: return value of `document.getElementsByTagName` is same as `Array`, but is live, that means if you add/remove `div` (using javascript, or via console), the result will be refreshed automatically. you need to provide an object and using `for` and fill the object.

Comment: To be clear, is your JavaScript writing the HTML to the page, just reading existing HTML, or reading *and modifying* existing HTML?

Answer (score 1):

are you looking for something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arrayDivs = [
        {
            title: 'Title 1',
            description: 'This is the description to Title 1',
            backgroundColor: 'gray',
            color: 'black'
        },
        {
            title: 'Title 2',
            description: 'This is the description to Title 2',
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            color: 'red'
        },
    ];
        
    function init() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayDivs.length; i++) {
            var html = '';
            html += '<div class="section" style="color:' + arrayDivs[i].color + '; background-color:' + arrayDivs[i].backgroundColor + ';">';
            html += '<h3>' + arrayDivs[i].title + '</h3>';
            html += '<p>' + arrayDivs[i].descritpion + '</p>';
            html += '</div>';
            $('.container').append(html);
        }
    };     
    init();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Some text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you mix vanilla JS and JQuery to build the content? E.g. `'<h3>' + arrayDivs[i].title + '</h3>'` is a very bad example (c.f. XSS).

Answer (score 1):

He I know JQuery you can do that with this

```js
     var div = {
        divInfo: [
          {
            title: "Title 1",
            description: "1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
          },
          {
            title: "Title 2",
            description: "2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
          },
          {
            title: "Title 3",
            description: "3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
          },
          {
            title: "Title 4",
            description: "4 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
          }        
        ]
      };
    
    $.each(div.divInfo,function(i,x){
     $('.container').append('<div class="wrapper"><h3>'+x.title+'<p>'+x.description+'</p></h3></div>')
    })
```

```css
.wrapper{
    background:skyblue;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jquery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate over each `.wrapper`:

```
var divs = [];
$('div.wrapper').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   divs.push({
       divinfo: {
           title: $this.find('h3').html(),
           description: $this.find('p').html()
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

sure, just an example...

```
var divArr = document.getElementsByTagName('DIV');

for (var i= 0; i < divArr.length; i++) {
  if (divArr[i].className !== 'container') {
    divArr[i].title = 'new title';
  }
}
```

Comment: tell me m0re, i'll help you 0ut.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying to create the HTML elements based on your array of information, you can use code like this:

```
// get the container element in which you want to insert divs
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

// loop through all the elements in your array
for(var i = 0, len = div.divInfo.length; i < len; i++){
    // create the actual div element to insert
    var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
    // specify element attributes here as necessary
    // append the element to the container
    container.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

Here's some working example code:

```js
var div = {
    divInfo: [
      {
        title: "title",
        description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing"
      },
      {
        title: "another title",
        description: "Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus."
      }
    ]
  };
var container = document.querySelector(".container");
for(var i = 0, len = div.divInfo.length; i < len; i++){
  var wrapper = document.createElement("div");
  wrapper.className = "wrapper";
  wrapper.style.backgroundColor = "#dfdfdf;"; 
  var header = document.createElement("h3");
  header.innerHTML = div.divInfo[i].title;
  var body = document.createElement("p");
  body.innerHTML = div.divInfo[i].description;
  wrapper.appendChild(header);
  wrapper.appendChild(body);
  container.appendChild(wrapper);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

If you're trying to create an array based on existing HTML elements on the page, you can use code like this:

```
// grab all the divs with the wrapper class, inside the element with the container class
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".container div.wrapper");
// loop through the results
for(var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++){
    var currentDiv = divs[i];
    // modify the elements or extract data from them here
}
```

Again, here's some working example code:

```js
var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".container div.wrapper");
var div = {divInfo:[]};
for(var i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++){
  var currentDiv = divs[i];
  var title = divs[i].querySelector("h3").innerHTML;
  var description = divs[i].querySelector("p").innerHTML;
  div.divInfo.push({title:title, description:description});
  currentDiv.style.backgroundColor = "#dfdfdf";
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "div = "+JSON.stringify(div);
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <h3>Title</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit</p>
   </div>
     <div class="wrapper">
      <h3>Another Title</h3>
      <p>Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.</p>
   </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<b>Code Result:</b>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Both of those examples update the background of the divs using `element.style.backgroundColor`.